# Getting all value from div in a array in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I am making a commenting system.

I have a condition where I have to put all commented users in an array like:

var allUser = [
 "bIJAYA",
 "Ram",
 "superuser",
 "Jack",
 "shyam",
 "Rohit",
 "Jinchu",
]

My DOM inspection is as below:

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <h3><span class="commmentBy">bIJAYA</span></h3>
   <label class="commentText">fds></label>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h3><span class="commmentBy">Ram</span></h3>
   <label class="commentText">fds></label>
 </li>    
 <li>
   <h3>
   <span class="commmentBy">superuser</span>
   </h3>
   <label class="commentText">sdf</label>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h3><span class="commmentBy">Jack</span></h3>
   <label class="commentText">fds></label>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h3><span class="commmentBy">shyam</span></h3>
   <label class="commentText">fds></label>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h3><span class="commmentBy">Rohit</span></h3>
   <label class="commentText">fds></label>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h3><span class="commmentBy">Jinchu</span></h3>
   <label class="commentText">fds></label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I need all commented users in an array as above.
Commented usernames have the `<span class="commmentBy"></span>` tag.

Help me to do this..

Comment: Start writing script..will help you for sure..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this it will help you

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
    var txt = $(this).find(".commmentBy").text();
        temp.push(txt);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kAZt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method for this:

```
var allUser = $('ul .commmentBy').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(allUser);
```

Comment: Now how can i filter distinct username from this .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` method

```
   var commentedArray = $('.commmentBy').map(function() {
       return $.trim($(this).text());
    }).get();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BY8GG/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = $('.commmentBy').map(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text())
}).get()
```